# C function for converting text to morse code

Tags: c, function, segmentation-fault, program-entry-point, morse-code

I'm trying to write a program where the morse code of the given text by the system is required. About the converting text to morse code, I wrote them all in main (separately from the program file itself). And now, my aim is to write it as a function in order to use it in the other functions of the program. Whenever I try, it gives a segmentation fault. Can anyone help me to construct the function itself from scratch?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

char * fileName1 = NULL;
char * fileName2 = NULL;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  int n;
  for (n = 0; n < argc; n++) {
    // printf("Argument %s\n",argv[n]); // prints options  delete this in the end,just for debugging
    if (strcmp(argv[n], "-text") == 0) {
      //text to morsecode
      int c, v = 0;
      char * str = (char * ) malloc(v);
      str = (char * ) realloc(str, (c + strlen(argv[n + 1])));
      strcat(str, argv[n + 1]);
      strcat(str, " ");

      char *alphamorse[]={".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."};
      char *nummorse[]={"-----",".----","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----."};

      int i;
      char str1[1000];
      i = 0;
      while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (str[i] != ' ' && (!isdigit(str[i]))) {
          printf("%s ", alphamorse[toupper(str[i]) - 65]);
        }
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
          printf(" ");
        }
        if (isdigit(str[i]) && str[i] != ' ') {
          printf("%s ", nummorse[str[i] - 48]);
        }
        i++;
      }
      printf("\n");
      // end of text to morsecode
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[n], "-o") == 0) {
      //output = concat(output, argv[n + 1]);
      n++;
      continue;
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[n], "--") == 0) {
      if (n + 1 <= argc) {
        fileName1 = argv[++n];
        printf("    fileName1=%s\n", fileName1);
      }
      if (n + 1 <= argc) {
        fileName2 = argv[++n];
        printf("    fileName2=%s\n", fileName2);
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume the magic numbers 65 and 48 are intended to represent `A` and `0`.  It is bad practice to use numbers like this in code rather than `'A'` and `'0'`, not only for readability but because those values will change depending on the character set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the bug that's causing an issue, but it is a bug:

```
int c, v = 0;
char *str = (char *)malloc(v);
    str = (char *)realloc(str, (c + strlen(argv[n+1])));
```

First, `c` is uninitialized.  It could be any value, including a negative value.  Hence, undefined behavior in your program.

Also, that malloc followed by a a realloc call isn't needed. Just allocate once and be done with it.

I think this is what you intended to do

```
size_t len = strlen(argv[n+1]);
str = (char*)malloc(len + 1 + 1); // +1 for space char to be appended, +1 again for null char
strcpy(str, argv[n+1]); // copy string
strcat(str, " ");       // append a space
```

But there's an even simpler solution.  You don't even need to copy `argv[n+1]` into `str`. Just declare `str` as a pointer and reference `argv[n+1]` directly.

```
const char* str = argv[n+1];
```

Now `str` and `argv[n+1]` reference the same string. And `str` is valid for the entirety of the program.  The rest of your program remains the same.

This looks suspicious:

```
  i = 0;
  while (str[i] != '\0') {
    if (str[i] != ' ' && (!isdigit(str[i]))) {
      printf("%s ", alphamorse[toupper(str[i]) - 65]);
    }
    if (str[i] == ' ') {
      printf(" ");
    }
    if (isdigit(str[i]) && str[i] != ' ') {
      printf("%s ", nummorse[str[i] - 48]);
    }
    i++;
  }
```

You are redundantly calling isdigit and evaluating to make sure `str[i]` is not a space. No point in checking if its a space if you already know it's a digit. Either it's a digit, a letter, or something that can't be converted.  Your code will errneously treat puncutation marks as values to lookup in `alphamorse`.  The following will skip over punctuation marks and just treat those characters as spaces.

```
  i = 0;
  while (str[i] != '\0') {

    if ((str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') || (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')) {
      printf("%s ", alphamorse[toupper(str[i]) - 'A']);
    }
    else if (isdigit(str[i])) {
      printf("%s ", nummorse[str[i] - '0']);
    }
    else {
        printf(" ");
    }
    i++;
  }
```

Everything after that, I don't know what it's for. General advice is that you parse the arguments from `argv[]` first.  Then do the text conversion outside of the loop that iterates over the command line arguments. Then do your save to file code.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need or want to be copying the parameters.  It seems easiest to just do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *alphamorse[] = {
        ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", /* A - J */
        "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", /* K - T */
        "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.." /* W - Z */
};
char *nummorse[]={
        "-----", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-",
        ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----."
};

void
text_to_morse(char c, FILE *out)
{
        if( islower(c) ) {
                fputs(alphamorse[c - 'a'], out);
                fputc(' ', out);
        } else if( isdigit(c) ) {
                fputs(nummorse[c - '0'], out);
                fputc(' ', out);
        } else if( isspace(c) ) {
                fputc(c, out);
        } else {
                fputc(' ', out);
        }
}

int
main(void)
{
        int c;
        while( ( c = tolower(getchar())) != EOF ) {
                text_to_morse(c, stdout);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Don't even bother with code for manipulating the output file.  The shell exists for a reason, and there's no need to reimplement the wheel.

Comment: hi! What if the function must get the text from the terminal by the user, not from the file and what if I need to use this data itself which I'm gonna get from the function as a morse code?

Comment: Read the text from stdin.  If the user wants to type it from the terminal, they will run the program with stdin coming from the terminal.   If the user wants the data to come from a file, they will run the program with stdin coming from the file.  If you need to use the data, you could pass it a FILE * created from fmemopen.